# Why API Gateway allows invalid dates

Tags: amazon-web-services, date, validation, jsonschema, api-gateway

In AWS API Gateway, I have a model like  this:

```json
{
  "required" : [ "validUntil" ],
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "validUntil" : {
      "$ref":"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/xxxyyyzzz/models/Timestamp"
    },
    "deadline" : {
      "$ref":"https://apigateway.amazonaws.com/restapis/xxxyyyzzz/models/Date"
    }
  }
}
```

When I pass a request with invalid timestamp, e.g. `2023-12-32T00:00:00+00:00`, i.e. December the 32nd, I get error as *expected*:

```
Gateway response body: {"errorCode":"BAD_REQUEST_BODY","message":"Invalid request body","description":"[format attribute \"date\" not supported, string \"2023-12-32T00:00:00+00:00\" is invalid against requested date format(s) [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ, yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ]]"}
```

That works fine.

Yet... when I pass `2023-12-32` as `deadline` which uses `Date` model then the request is valid:

```
Request validation succeeded for content type application/json
```

Why is that? **Why API Gateway doesn't trigger error?**

Here are my models:

**Date:**

```json
{
  "type" : "string",
  "description" : "Date in ISO 8601 format.",
  "format" : "date"
}
```

**Timestamp**

```json
{
  "type" : "string",
  "description" : "Timestamp as defined by ISO 8601 with time offset.",
  "format" : "date-time"
}
```

JSON Schema specification: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#dates-and-times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From API Gateway documentation (in June 2023):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings-models.html

> In API Gateway, models are defined using the JSON schema **draft 4**

Linked JSON Schema spec with `date` format is from **draft 7**

[image]

Thus, as API Gateway is using older specification, it doesn't validate `date` format as assumed.

Answer (score 1):

The section of the JSON Schema spec which you linked to states that the `date` type is **new in draft 7**, whereas the `date-time` type has been around for a longer time.

[image]

The AWS API gateway [uses an old version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings-models.html) of the JSON Schema spec, so it does not understand the `date` type.